# How to get rid of " " in open files

Tags: c++

I've got something like this

```
/sth/sth/sth/SOMETHINGTHATISCHANGING/sth/sth.txt


string tab[5]={"nicefolder","betterfolder","bestofall","dog","readingthis"};
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
fstream file;
file.open("/sth/sth/sth/"tab[i]"/sth/sth.txt", ios::in);
//shit to do
}
```

I know it do not work but just want to show you what I need to achieve.
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to perform string concatenation, you can use the `+` operator

```
file.open("/sth/sth/sth/" + tab[i] + "/sth/sth.txt", ios::in);
```

By the way, the `fstream` constructor can take these arguments so you don't need to make a separate `open` call

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    fstream file{"/sth/sth/sth/" + tab[i] + "/sth/sth.txt", ios::in};
}
```

Comment: I've got     error: no matching function for call to 'std::basic_fstream<char>::open(std::basic_string<char>, const openmode&)'|

Comment: Another alternative is to use a temporary `std::string` to build the filename, then use `std::string::c_str()` inside the `fstream` constructor (or `open` method).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews No need for `c_str`.

Comment: Indeed path[0].c_str() and path[0] works aswell.
Strange I would swear that i've checked path[0] option(first thing i thought about), strange.